# Web server files being publicly served despite permissions set to user/group only

Tags: linux, debian, permissions, web-server, apache-2.4

I'm running an Apache2 server on Raspbian that serves an instance of DokuWiki, however I seem to be running into permissions issues.

For some reason all my directories and the files in them are accessible publicly on the server. All the directories are recursively set to chmod *770*, I even tried *700*, yet I can still access them in the browser. I previously had it set up where everything was owned by my user, *pi*, but even when putting everything under the *www-data* user, I can't get it to work.

There are .htaccess files that come with DokuWiki that are also supposed to prevent access but those are not functioning either. I've enabled *mod-rewrite* and *AllowOverride All*, still no luck...

**Example of my permissions setup:**

```
pi@piserver:/var/www/html $ ls -al
total 96
drwxr-xr-x  9 www-data www-data  4096 May 24 03:15 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root      4096 May 24 02:21 ..
drwxrwx---  2 www-data www-data  4096 May 24 02:39 bin
drwxrwx---  2 www-data www-data  4096 May 24 03:02 conf
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 18092 May 24 02:39 COPYING
drwxrwx--- 12 www-data www-data  4096 May 24 02:39 data
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  3674 May 24 02:39 doku.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 19372 May 24 02:39 feed.php
-rwxr-x---  1 www-data www-data    66 May 24 03:15 .htaccess
drwxrwxr-x  6 www-data www-data  4096 May 24 02:39 inc
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   182 May 24 02:39 index.php
drwxrwxr-x  8 www-data www-data  4096 May 24 02:39 lib
drwxrwx---  2 www-data www-data  4096 May 24 03:03 old
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   306 May 24 02:39 README
drwxrwx---  5 www-data www-data  4096 May 24 02:40 vendor
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    23 May 24 02:39 VERSION

pi@piserver:/var/www/html/data $ ls -al
total 100
drwxrwx--- 12 www-data www-data  4096 May 24 02:39 .
drwxr-xr-x  9 www-data www-data  4096 May 24 03:15 ..
drwxrwx---  2 www-data www-data  4096 May 24 03:08 attic
drwxrwx--- 16 www-data www-data  4096 May 24 03:08 cache
-rwxrwx---  1 www-data www-data 20836 May 24 02:39 deleted.files
-rwxrwx---  1 www-data www-data    32 May 24 02:39 _dummy
-rwxrwx---  1 www-data www-data    31 May 24 02:39 .htaccess
drwxrwx---  2 www-data www-data  4096 May 24 03:08 index
drwxrwx---  2 www-data www-data  4096 May 24 03:08 locks
drwxrwx---  3 www-data www-data  4096 May 24 02:39 media
drwxrwx---  2 www-data www-data  4096 May 24 02:39 media_attic
drwxrwx---  2 www-data www-data  4096 May 24 02:39 media_meta
drwxrwx---  3 www-data www-data  4096 May 24 03:08 meta
drwxrwx---  4 www-data www-data  4096 May 24 03:08 pages
-rwxrwx---  1 www-data www-data  6516 May 24 02:39 security.png
-rwxrwx---  1 www-data www-data 12093 May 24 02:39 security.xcf
drwxrwx---  2 www-data www-data  4096 May 24 02:39 tmp
```

**My .htaccess files look like this:**

```
order allow,deny
deny from all
```

***What exactly am I doing wrong here?***

Comment: Check your logs.

Comment: @MichaelHampton What should I be looking for? The error.log shows nothing of use, the access.log just shows the following:
`192.168.1.99 - - [24/May/2016:04:24:41 +0000] "GET /data/ HTTP/1.1" 200 903 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0"`

Comment: Can you show us the relevant config? Are `.htaccess` files enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out `AllowOverride All` was not set for the `/var/www` directory, once I set that in the Apache configuration, all went well.